# Unable to upload thumbnail for file using Google Drive Java SDK

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I've been working on App that allows to open files for which Google Drive cannot generate thumbnails, but the app I'm working on can. I've been following this article: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/file#uploading_thumbnails and have the following code in my app as a result:

```
File file = drive.files().get(fileId).setFields("id,name,headRevisionId,hasThumbnail,contentHints").execute();
if (file != null && file.getHeadRevisionId().equals(versionId)) {
    File.ContentHints.Thumbnail customThumbnail = new File.ContentHints.Thumbnail();
    customThumbnail.encodeImage(imageData);
    customThumbnail.setMimeType("image/png");
    File.ContentHints contentHints = new File.ContentHints();
    contentHints.setThumbnail(customThumbnail);
    drive.files().update(fileId, new File().setContentHints(contentHints)).execute();
}
```

Image exists - imageData is byte[] and it has proper data in it. It seems that Google Drive retrieves this data because if I try to open preview of the file I've uploaded thumbnail for (on drive.google.com) - it tries to load it, but constantly shows "Failed, retrying".

If I do "non-safe" base64 encoding - I'm able to open this image URL in browser and any viewer and I've tried to pass this "non-safe" base64 encoded string, but the result is the same.

Is there something wrong with my code or I'm missing something in documentation or it's an issue on Google Drive side?

Comment: What type/size/width/height does your thumbnail have? Does this happen with multiple files, or just the one? Have you tried the same with other thumbnails for the same file?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo, thumbnails are pngs 250*250px. Size is ~3-4 kB. This happens with all the files I've tested. I've checked with my own files under subfolder in "My Drive". Let me try to pass some random thumbnail to see if this helps

Comment: How are you getting setting the value of `imageData`?

Comment: It's actually received from AWS s3 like this:
```GetObjectRequest gor = new GetObjectRequest(bucket, id);
        try (S3Object obj = s3.getObject(gor)) {
            return IOUtils.toByteArray(obj.getObjectContent());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new byte[0];
        }```

I've double-checked that it returns correct byte array. Again - if I convert it to base64 encoded string and try to view it in browser, then it works

Comment: So for example - there's a thumbnail that is just a circle. If I use `java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(imageData)` and then prepend it with `data:image/png;base64,` - it opens in Chrome.

Comment: Just curious - have you tried prepending the `data:image/png;base64,` before conveting to byte array? Not sure if it'll fix anything but just trying to narrow down possibilities